# JMeter Http Request connect timeout forever

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter

I'm using JMeter to test Spring Boot REST API server.

JMeter options are

```
Concurrent users : 200
Ramp-up period : 10 seconds
Loop Count : 500
```

The test going well until 1-20000 requests,

but please see next images.

[image: Request]

Average response time is below 10ms, but sometimes over 20~50ms.

[image: Transaction]

When response time increases, connect timeout occurrs.

Even if I set the connect timeout over 10 minutes.

[image: Connect Timeout Error]

Why this error occurred? I can't find it..

Comment: They're in Spring Boot's application.properties(```server.tomcat.connection-timeout```) and JMeter's (```HTTP Request - Timeout - Connect```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [ConnectTimeoutException](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.9/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html) documentation:

> A timeout while connecting to an HTTP server or waiting for an available connection from an HttpConnectionManager.

So there are 2 possible reasons:

1. Your server fails to process the incoming connections, it might be due to:

   - Incorrect [connection pool configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-tomcat-connection-pool), amend the settings to match your load pattern
   - Lack of resources, use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to monitor whether the server has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network sockets, etc.
   - Inefficient algorithms or bugs in your API implementation, use a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to see where and why your application spends > 10 minutes before /instead of responding
2. JMeter doesn't have enough resources in order to conduct the required load

   - Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - If it's not enough - consider switching to [distributed testing mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: I think JMeter's GUI mode was problem. I've tested JMeter with CLI mode on server computer, it worked well. Thank you.